# Is there a difference of using lightning-layout VS <div class="slds-grid">?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds-grid

There are 2 ways to create flex layout in salesforce lwc: `lightning-layout` and `<div class="slds-grid">`. If we use Chrome dev tools, we'll notice that `lightning-layout` compliles into `<lightning-layout class="slds-grid">`. It is practically (not technically because it is a custom component) the same as `<div class="slds-grid">`. So the question is simple should we use `lightning-layout` or `<div class="slds-grid">` to build layouts in Lighting Experience? Assuming that `slds-grid` css class and other grid-related classes are added to `lightning-layout` at runtime on client, can it have a significant performance impact?

Answer (score 4):

Use lightning-layout instead of CSS when possible. This allows for compatibility with any future changes that may be made to SLDS. The difference in performance shouldn't be that extreme under normal circumstances. As long as you keep it under about ~10,000 components or so, you should be fine. As a point of reference, I was able to get Conway's Game of Life running at a reasonable speed using only native redraws for a 100x100 grid of cells; I could have easily made it run better with direct CSS manipulation or canvas draws, but the point was, it was good enough for casual use. Just keep the usage to a reasonable level, you'll be fine.

Comment: I disagree. I believe that using tools like lightning-layout is an anti pattern (the inner platform effect). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect. Changes to SLDS are few and far between and `lightning-layout` is a subset of a perfectly good css framework. Plus, as you say it's slower. So what's to like?

Comment: @CasparHarmer I like sensible auto-completion and compile-time safety checks. I still forget that `slds-wrap` is what I need for multiple rows (without checking docs), but `multiple-rows` is an obvious, if not slightly longer, way to write my intent. CSS frameworks as a whole are generally difficult to work with (SLDS is *really* bad to work with, IMHO), but components make this bearable. In fact, I made components for things like `slds-form` so I don't have to remember all the semantics.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, at the risk of starting a flame war, I believe there are good reasons to avoid things like `lightning-layout`.

1. It's an example of an anti-pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect (building a new system on an existing perfectly good system)
2. It is a subset of a very good css system (flexbox) but it doesn't quite have all the power that that system provides.
3. Breaking changes are rare. Fixing them is generally quite easy.
4. A wider set of developers can read your code (not just salesforce developers).
5. Cognitive load of having to learn another framework is significant.
6. Performance is not as good. I know that there is an argument that just a little hit to performance is not bad... but EVERYONE is making those arguments. And the hits to performance are additive. Right now, modern web pages are slower that ever before. And it's because of all these little things.

So my advice to you is just use the CSS framework. I've been using almost raw slds css + html for years now and have not yet had to refactor anything.

Comment: Not really a sort of  war thing, I just feel like this list is largely subjective. None of these points would convince me to switch to monolithic CSS-only components over modular, reusable snippets that take the guess-work out of developing a UI. If anything, Lightning is still *missing* some critical components, like slds-form/slds-form_element support. Most of the slowness problems with Lightning are Locker Service issues anyways, not a choice of CSS vs. Components. Still, using CSS-only isn't useless, and is a valid preference choice.

Comment: I think it's the question really... answers are likely to be skewed towards being opinion based.